# How to track the error log on running devices using robotium?

Tags: robotium

I'm not running robotium test case using command prompt, instead i am navigating to Dev Tools and finding the suite on that and running it and it is working fine for me on the Emulator.

But in case if it is failure, it is exiting the app. I just wanted to know that how to collect the logs to verify that which test case is failed.

The same way i need to know that is there anyway, i can run the suite from devices without connecting to PC (like how i am running on emulator using Dev tools)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change your instrumentationtest runner to something like:

http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/

then an xml file will be created containing all your test runs. This will also be useful as it is in standard junit xml format so you can put it into any CI system and it should work.

Comment: Hi, This seems to be the device connected with usb to run the command from cmd prompt. I am looking out to run the test case on standalone without connecting the device..

Comment: take this file and use it as your instrumentation runner, it will create a results file. By default it will be in your applications space but you can change it to be somewhere else in that code, for example an SD card. You will then be able to pull this results file off the phone or look at it directly.

Comment: Hi Paul, Can you please little elaborate this? As per the link, I understand the step 1 but for step 2, i need to connect the device right?

Comment: You can use a file browser to look for the file.